# Enable/press scroll lock at login screen

Tags: keyboard, login-screen, keyboard-backlight

I have an illuminated keyboard, I have to press the scroll lock key for it to light up, how can I enable this at the login screen?

I see there is a similar thing for NumLock here (question 776961)

Running Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

Add this command to start up:

```
xset led named "Scroll Lock"
```

To do so search for "Startup Applications Preferences" or run this in the terminal:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Then add the start up command
[image: Add a startup command]